# C++ class template instantiation delay, STL bitset

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stl, initialization

I know the following code is wrong. I should a give fixed constant N, but I want to change this to a variable N.

```cpp
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

class C {
 public:
  C(int N) {
    bitset<N> b;
  }
};

int main() {
  C c(123); // How to coding it?
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<bool>`? /me is hiding...

Comment: You can use boost [Dynamic Bitset](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)

Comment: The template parameter is required at compile time, not run time, so this will not work. As @Jarod42 mentioned, if you need a dynamic size, a `std::vector<bool>` may still suit your needs.

Comment: @Jarod42 No need to hide... We all have to deal with the pain that the specialized size optimization of `std::vector<bool>` brings, we might as well make use of it.

Comment: BTW, packing for specialization of `std::vector<bool>` is optional.

Comment: @Jarod42 `std::vector<bool>` need 4 bits every element, bitset only need small memory.

Comment: With packing specialization, you should have similar memory usage between `std::bitset` and `std::vector<bool>`, (vector would have extra members for capacity and size).